# A pair of dice is cast until either the sum of seven or eight appears.

Tags: probability

The problem: A pair of dice is cast until either the sum of seven or eight appears.

(a) Show that the probability of a seven before an eight is 6/11.

(b) Next, this pair of dice is cast until a seven appears twice or until each of a six and eight have appeared at least once. Show that the probability of the six and eight occurring before two sevens is 0.546.

**My question is how can we calculate 8 will be cast after 7 when, if 7 is cast, the cast will just stop casting? I don't understand the question above.**

Comment: Just calculate the probability that a $7$ appears *first*---of course an $8$ will appear *sometime* later....

Comment: In the first case, we have a bet.  My number is $7$ and yours is $8$.  Whoever's number comes up first is the winner.  (Then we stop rolling as you say.)  The probability that I will win is $6/11$.  This is what you have to show.  In the second case, the bet is more complicated.  I win if $7$ comes up twice before both $6$ and $8$ have shown up, otherwise, you win.  In both cases, we are betting on which event occurs first.

Comment: For (a), the condition is satisfied on the $n$th throw provided the first $n-1$ throws summed to neither 7 nor 8. The probability that a given throw doesn't sum to 7 or 8 is $1 - (P(7) + P(8)) = 1 - (12/36 + 10/36) = 14/36$. So, the probability that condition (a) is satifsfied on the $n$th throw is  $(14/36)^{n-1} \cdot 12/36$ (where $12/36$ is the probability of rolling a sum of 7 on n-th throw). Summing over all $n$ gives $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (14/36)^{n-1} \cdot (12/36) = 1/3 \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (7/18)^n = 1/3 \cdot  \frac{1}{1 - 7/18} = 6/11$.

Comment: @andy87 Actually, more simply it's just $\frac{12/36}{12/36 + 10/36} = \frac{12}{22} = \frac{6}{11}$.

Comment: @David G. Stork@saulspatz this makes sense, otherwise 8 will never appear after 7 has occured and the probability is 0.

Comment: @andy87 you answer is very close to [link](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/a-pair-of-dice-is-cast-until-either-the-sum-of-seven-or-eight-appears-a-show-that-the-probability-of/#) . you just need change the p(7) p(8) value

Comment: @JohnOmielan I'm having trouble conceptualizing $\frac{12/36}{12/36 + 10/36}$. Would you be willing to explain the intuition? What insight or principle allows us to go straight to that? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnOmielan Actually, I just found this answer to basically the same original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646401/448834. I think I get it now.

Comment: @JohnOmielan (Sorry if these are bugging you) My intuition for your expression is now this (from reading the answer I linked): The game stops at step $n$ if and only if we roll a 7 or an 8 at step $n$. Moreover, each roll is independent of the rolls before. Thus, the outcome space is effectively reduced to 7s or 8s, making the probability of rolling a 7 $\frac{12/36}{12/36 + 10/36}$.

Comment: @andy87 Don't worry; you're not bugging me. I was gone for a while, so I didn't get a chance to respond to you earlier. Note I used your values for $7$ and $8$, which are actually double what they should be. Also, in terms of the insight, the answers to that question, especially by [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%c3%a9-nicolas), explain the reasoning. Also, your explanation above is correct, but the expression is actually $\frac{6/36}{6/36 + 5/36}$, although it still results in the same final value of $\frac{6}{11}$.

Comment: @John Omielan Andre nicolas’s explanation can’t explain the situation that only one time casting is allowed in which the probability should not use conditional probability, what do you think

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yikes, I didn't realize I was double-counting. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @ETakly I'm not quite sure what you're asking. You could use conditional probability, but it's not necessary in this case. Here's how I view it & perhaps it'll help you too. Regardless of how many previous steps were used, the ratio of the probability of getting a sum of $7$ to that of an $8$ is always the same, i.e., $\frac{6/36}{5/36} = \frac{6}{5}$. Adding these values together, regardless of how many or what they are individually, will give you a result where this ratio holds. Thus, as the sum of all gives $1$, this means the probability of $7$ is $\frac{6}{6 + 5} = \frac{6}{11}$.

Comment: @ETakly You're correct. Casting just one time only, a probability of a $7$ before a $8$ (or any other sum of $2$ die) is just the probability of a $7$, which is $6/36$. The $6/11$ result comes from requiring possibly multiple casts, stopping only when one of $2$ things first happen: either a $7$ occurs or an $8$ occurs.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I mean if we changed the game rule to only cast one time, the probability of a 7 before a 8 is 6/36, not 6/11. the conditional probability can only be applied to unlimited time casting

Comment: @ETakly Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the question is asking about the *probability* of a $7$ appearing before an $8$. Note in any given set of casts, if a $7$ appears, then you will stop so you won't get an $8$. Likewise, if you get an $8$ first, you'll stop then so you won't get a $7$ afterwards.

However, say you repeat this casting many times. There will be cases where a $7$ appears first and others where an $8$ appears first. If you keep track of how often each case occurs and then divide the # of times a $7$ appears first by the total number of trials, this ratio should approach $6/11$ as the number of trials used increases. This is basically what probability is about, but there are mathematical methods to make this more precise and easier to deal with.

The second part is more complicated, but it still involves the same basic ideas.

Comment: this makes sense, otherwise 8 will never happen after 7 has occured and the probability is 0.